# EXECUTE AS SYS ADMIN AND XP_CMDSHELL

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure where I use xp_cmdshell to check for a file in a remote directory. My SQL Server Service Account does not have access to to folder so I am trying to use EXECUTE AS to run the xp_cmdshell under a user who has access to sql server as well as to the folder.

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'domain\user1'
exec xp_cmdShell 'dir \\app01\d$\files\ /B'
```

user1 is a server sys admin. So from my understanding I'm thinking this should work but I get the error:

```
Msg 15406, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "domain\user1" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.
```

Do I need to use a non-admin account so it will use the proxy account? The proxy account is domain\user1.